Working Nested Select - support with building right query
Some details before.... From Assignment table I would like to get Resource name and "Resource>ReportsTo>Name/Email" and be able actually to filter by "Resource>ReportsTo>Name/Email"
I'm using Google Spredsheets and Addon Google Connector for Salesforce to execute queries

Assignment API name is "pse__Assignment__c" and have "Resource" field "pse__Resource__c", type of Lookup(Contact)

Contact API name is "Contact" and have "Reports To" field "ReportsToId", type of Lookup(Contact)


I'm able to make it work by such query:
SELECT
  pse__Project__r.Project_Number_ERP__c,
    pse__Project__r.Name,
    pse__Resource__r.Name,
    pse__Resource__r.Person_ID__c,
    pse__Resource__r.Email,
    Assignment_Status__c,
    pse__Start_Date__c,
    pse__End_Date__c,
    Billing_Role__c,
    pse__Bill_Rate__c,
    pse__Percent_Allocated__c,
    pse__Cost_Rate_Currency_Code__c,
    pse__Daily_Bill_Rate__c,
    pse__Resource__r.ReportsTo.Email
FROM
    pse__Assignment__c
    
WHERE
    pse__Resource__r.ReportsTo.Email IN ('email1','email2','email3')
  AND
    (pse__Start_Date__c <= LAST_MONTH AND pse__End_Date__c >= LAST_MONTH)
    

But:

I need to use Salesforce object Ids to get  data
In return I'm able to get only some orf of JSON of ReportsTo.Email like "{Email=email1, attributes={type=Contact, url=/services/data/v62.0/sobjects/Contact/0036M000049j8WDQAY}}"

What I need is:

Keep more or less returned fields

Be able to select from pse__Assignment__c based on pse__Resource__r.ReportsToId.Email field

Have returned normal value of pse__Resource__r.ReportsTo.Email field instead of "JSON" like "{Email=email1, attributes={type=Contact, url=/services/data/v62.0/sobjects/Contact/0036M000049j8WDQAY}}".


despite all my tries, I was never able to build working query which would solve this and Your support would be greatly appreciated.
I have read SOQL manual but either its not applicable to my case either my experience with SQL blinds me and I cannot build it.

Hi and welcome to SFSE. Is there a specific question here? I can't work out what the problem is and what you cannot do. Could you please [edit] the question to clarify what you need. What is the context for running the SOQL query? Is this to be performed in Apex, or using REST API or something else? Please ensure you add context and a specific set of questions when you update the question.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@PhilW - I have updated questions with what I need in the end

To eliminate hard coded Id values you can use a subquery in the where clause.
And where there is a lookup Id field, a relationship reference is also supported and you can query up to 5 levels of these.
So try something like this:
    ...
    pse__Resource__r.ReportsToId,
    pse__Resource__r.ReportsTo.Name,
    pse__Resource__r.ReportsTo.Email
from
    pse__Assignment__c
where
    pse__Resource__r.ReportsToId in (
        select Id from Contact where Name = :name or Email = :email
    )
and
    ...


This is a reasonable answer, though for me the question isn't clear. Does the logic have to be done fully in one query, or does this data come from elsewhere (such as the name and email bindings you have suggested). Hence my question about what context is relevant.

Hey, I can execute query select Id from Contact where Name = "mycompanyemail" but putting this into WHERE pse__Resource__r.ReportsToId in ( SELECT ID...) returns me "The query is not well formed. Please review the query". But.... using WHERE pse__Resource__r.ReportsTo.Email IN ("email1","email2") worked... so its partially solved my need. But... using "pse__Resource__r.ReportsTo.Email" returns me some sorf of JSON like this "{Email=companyemail, attributes={type=Contact, url=/services/data/v62.0/sobjects/Contact/0036M000049j8WDQAY}}

Hi @Lemonek, A good way to develop queries is to write a unit test for the query. But that JSON looks like the entire Contact not just the email address; did you include the .Email in the debug?

Hi @KeithC I have limited  or actually no option to debug as Im standard user so all my "operations" are done trough GoogleSpreadsheet addon Google Connector for Salesforce, and yes - I have included .Email - I have updated my question with up to date query.

The format you show looks like an API representation of an SObject, in this case a Contact, with the Email field populated. What's wrong with that? This is how it is.
I would expect it to also contain the Name and Person_ID__c values as well - you are returning some details from a related record using:
    pse__Resource__r.Name,
    pse__Resource__r.Person_ID__c,
    pse__Resource__r.Email,

To get these "inline", you would need to add three cross-object formula fields in pse__Assignment__c, one for each of these, and change the query to return these values instead.
E.g. adding ResourceEmail__c that is a Text formula with a formula of pse__Resource__r.Email and then retrieving ResourceEmail__c in the pse__Assignment__c will avoid that field being put into a related record representation.

Hey Phil, for the "second" level it works just fine, problem occurs on "3rd" level of reference. I'm a complete noob when it takes to salesforce and my access level does not even allow me to test things. I was hoping that it would be possible to perform some sorf of nested SELECTs to get inline value, but if its not possible - then I will have to reprocess data in macro after its downloaded, not a big deal but at first look it a bit "ugly" value to preview data. I have tested other extention which seems to work as intended for 3rd level - so maybe my problem is Google Extention that SOQL
